# Finding explicit flow of a vector field

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, curves, vector-fields

I am working in a Differential Geometry problem which involves finding the explicit flow of the following vector field
$$X=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}-z\log z\tan y\frac{\partial}{\partial z}.$$
Its domain is the open set $W\subset\mathbb R^3$, where
$$W=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3\,|\,-\pi/2<y<\pi/2,\,z>0\}.$$
By applying the separation of variables method, we find that
$$\gamma(t)=\big(x,y+t,e^{\cos(y+t)}\big)$$
is an integral curve of $X$ that passes through the point $(x,y,e^{\cos(y)})$ at $t=0$. I would like to find, however, integral curves that pass through $(x,y,z)$, for any arbitrary $z>0$.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there. You just need to solve the IVP $\dot{z}(t)=-z(t)\log z(t)\,\tan(y_0+t)$, with $z(0)=z_0$. The solution is
\begin{align}
z(t)&=e^{\frac{\log z_0}{\cos y_0}\cos(y_0+t)},
\end{align}
defined for $t\in\Bbb{R}$ such that $y_0+t\in \left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$. So, really, all you were missing was a constant of integration, $A$, in $z(t)=e^{A\cos(y(t))}$.

So, the flow is the map $\Phi:\Omega\to W$,
\begin{align}
\Phi_t(x,y,z)=\left(x,y+t,e^{\frac{\log z}{\cos y}\cos(y+t)}\right),
\end{align}
where $\Omega=\{(t,x,y,z)\in\Bbb{R}^4\,:\, \text{$t+y\in (-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ and $y\in (-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ and $z>0$}\}$. As expected, the flow is incomplete.

Comment: Allright, thanks. I tried manipulating the map I gave, but I ran out of ideas.